# NSURLConnection The certificate for this server is invalid

Tags: swift, ssl, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

Recently I've been trying to connect to a test server of mine using a self-signed SSL certificate using `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest()`

Now I get this error:

```
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “...” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

I've been searching the web for how to solve it.
All of them advised for using one of these:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: NSURLProtectionSpace) -> Bool

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge)

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge)  

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void)
```

Now, when I ran my app I noticed that only

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge)
```

ran.

This is my code:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge)
{
    // Trusting and not trusting connection to host: Self-signed certificate
    challenge.sender.useCredential(NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust), forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
    challenge.sender.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)

    if(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust)
    {
        let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust
        let cred = NSURLCredential(forTrust: trust)

        challenge.sender.useCredential(cred, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
    }
}
```

Yet I keep getting `NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! Apparently I've had a `let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)` a bit before that I haven't noticed...

And I changed `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest()`
to 
 `let task = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()).dataTaskWithRequest(request)`

And left in place the delegate methods... that did it :)